# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK'), cannot read a local xlsx file in browser with ExcelJs in nextjs

Tags: next.js, exceljs

i have been trying to read and `fetch data` from a local Excel file located at the project folder itself, and using excel js while `readFile()` it reads in vsCode terminal but it shows the Error.

**`"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK')`**" while runnig on browser...

Here is the code:

```
async function readExcel() {
    const filePath ='result.xlsx'
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    
    try {
      await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(() => {
        console.log("File read");
      });
      const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1')
      const title = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).value;
      console.log(title);
     
    } catch (error) {
      throw(error);
    }
}
```

i want to get data from specific columns from the excel file located in my project folder, and using exceljs library it works fine in my terminal and not on browser.